# Wiki link to nonexistent page (aka red link)

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages

How do you create a link to a page that does not exist yet so that it encourages users to create that page? I like Wikipedia's feature of a [red link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Red_link), which does just that, and would like to replicate it in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that SharePoint works much the same way as Wikipedia. If you create a link with the double braces like this: `[[my new page]]`, ignore the popup empty page suggestion list. Then when you save the page, the link shows in a slightly different style. When you click on it, it gives you the option to create that page.

Comment: Does this still work with Sharepoint 2019? I can create a _red link_ (although it is not red), when I click on it, I just get a message that the page is missing.